# How to create time based triggers in Multiple Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to install a time based trigger on multiple Google Sheets using Google Apps Scripts and can't figure out how to do so.  I know these can be added through the UI but I was hoping to find a programmatic way to do this.  I have tried this code:

```
function initializeTrigger(sheetID){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myLibrary.myFunction')
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(9)
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}

function installMultipleTriggers(){
  var sheetList = [sheetID1, sheetID2, sheetID3];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetList.length; i++)
  {
    initializeTrigger(sheetList[i]);
  }
}
```

But when I run this I receive the error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function timeBased in object SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder.

Which makes sense I guess, because according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder), the SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder class doesn't have a method named timeBased()...  Does anyone know how to add time-based triggers to multiple Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3):

A time based trigger is independent of a sheet based trigger. Sheet based triggers respond to events that occur on the sheet, for example if you edit a cell.

I would eliminate the forSpreadsheet call in your code snippet, that should resolve your issue.

Comment: That would get the code to run but the trigger would only apply to the current spreadsheet.  I would like to apply the trigger to multiple spreadsheets.

Comment: @PatrickDoyle You'll need to collect the sheets you want to modify into an array and then loop over them, incrementally adding time-based triggers as you go. You should look into Arrays and For loops.

Answer (score 0):

## Create Spreadsheet Triggers Programatically

So I guess the issue here is that you wish to tie the triggers to a spreadsheet.  I believe that only way to do that is to create the triggers from a project that is contained by the spreadsheet and you can just use ClockTriggerBuilder.

Comment: This code will create a trigger on my current Spreadsheet but I am trying to install a trigger on multiple spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Access sheets in loop and assign trigger that may be only option

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).